# Align lines of two separate files in two split-windows?

Tags: scrolling

Is there a way to align line numbers of separate buffers, one in each split window?

Comment: Please consider reframing your question. It apparently has nothing to do with `follow-mode` and is just asking how to scroll two windows at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ScrollAllMode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScrollAllMode):

```
(defun mwheel-scroll-all-function-all (func &optional arg)
  (if (and scroll-all-mode arg)
      (save-selected-window
        (walk-windows
         (lambda (win)
           (select-window win)
           (condition-case nil
               (funcall func arg)
             (error nil)))))
    (funcall func arg)))

(defun mwheel-scroll-all-scroll-up-all (&optional arg)
  (mwheel-scroll-all-function-all 'scroll-up arg))

(defun mwheel-scroll-all-scroll-down-all (&optional arg)
  (mwheel-scroll-all-function-all 'scroll-down arg))

(setq mwheel-scroll-up-function 'mwheel-scroll-all-scroll-up-all)
(setq mwheel-scroll-down-function 'mwheel-scroll-all-scroll-down-all)
```